# Dynamic Image Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am really not sure how to go about doing this, but here is what I am trying to do. I am calling a static image from an API server that takes params height and width to know how big the image should be when it gets generated.

Now my site is css dynamic meaning it scales based on the browsers dimensions and even works for mobile browsers. My question is, how would I go about determining what parameters for height and width. I was thinking of using javascript to get the height and width of a similar size div and then use those.

Any other ideas?

Comment: js is about the **ONLY** way you can get the height/width of the browser window

Answer (score 3):

Just set `width:100%` (or whatever width) and the height will automatically be the correct size for the ascept ratio to be maintained.

Comment: But I need the height and width for the API call

Comment: @Pat841 - why would you need to send the height of an image that comes from the API... to the API?

Comment: @Pat841 - `window.innerHeight`?